# Display images in visual studio with Django and html [django]

Tags: django, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, django-templates, visual-studio-2019

im trying display pictures on my html page using D jango but its not displaying

it show like this

[image]

I add this code in the setting

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))


MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and this at the end of url

```
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

i have html page and i wrote image code like this

```
<img src="images/offer.jpg" alt="" />
```

and this is my files

[image]

hope I find solution here

Answer (score 0):

i solved it

i changed the code to

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "app/images/offer.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

ahhh finally thx god :D hope this help anyone have same problem